# What does (.browser-default).valid mean?

Tags: css

Currently I was going through some code over internet and I found this part of the code `input[type=text]:not(.browser-default).valid`. In the following code I know what :not is used for. However I have following question:

1. What does `(.browser-default)` part of the code does and where can I find more information about it?
2. I know what is `:valid` but not `.valid`? What it does and where can I read its exact functionality?

Comment: You're selecting text inputs with the `valid` class that don't have `browser-default` class - The dot (`.`) simply refer to a class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both .`browser-default` and `.valid` are user-defined class names. They are not part of the CSS Selectors Module - so you won't find more information about them!

In contrast, [:not](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation-pseudo) and [:valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#validity-pseudos) are CSS pseudo classes and *are* defined within the [CSS selectors module](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/).

So basically, the selector

```
input[type=text]:not(.browser-default).valid
```

matches a text input with a class `valid` and without a class `browser-default`

Comment: Thanks @Danield, with that explanation if I want to match a text input without two class it should be :not(.classOne)(.classTwo)??

Comment: Almost:   `:not(.classOne):not(.classTwo)` - we can chain the :not pseudo class multiple times

Answer (score 0):

> `.browser-default` and `.valid` are class names that programmer defined in his code and thay are not keyword in css.

```
input[type=text]:not(.browser-default).valid
```

*this selector, selects input if it have the following conditions:*

**input have :**

1) attribute `type` with value `text`.

2) class `valid`

**And have not :**

1) class `browser-default`

**See this example :**

```css
 input[type=text]:not(.browser-default).valid {
    background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="valid">
<br>
<input type="text" class="browser-default valid" name="">
```